# Using RTSP protocol as content source for Windows Media Services

Tags: silverlight, rtsp, live-streaming, windows-media-server

I need to play content from a video camera into a web page. I'm trying for now, to use a silverlight player (which seems to work ok with publishing points from WMS). The problem is that the camera is using RTSP protocol, and the player doens't seem to know this...

So I was thinking of using WMS to create a publish point for the stream that comes from camera, but I couldn't set up the publishing point to accept the rtsp source, it gives me an error saying that "Invalid or corupt data was encountered".

Is there any way to use rtsp as content source? If it is maybe you can point some details that I should be carefull of?

The camera works with "rtsp://192.168.1.22/profile4/media.smp" (tested in VLC player)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I received an answer from the camera manufacturer support team:

> WMS does NOT support RTSP Stream. Please use VLC player or Quick Time
>   Player.

I don' know if they are actually right...